# Using a separate method is a correct solution?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem from the book programming challenges by Skiena and when submitted to the online judge, one solution passed while the other one failed.

I'm trying to understand why one is an acceptable answer and the other is not. The only difference seems that one uses a separate method while the other does not. In which test would the second solution fail?

problem goes as follows:

The 3n + 1 problem

Consider the following algorithm to generate a sequence of numbers. Start with an integer n. If n is even, divide by 2. If n is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1. Repeat this process with the new value of n, terminating when n = 1. For example, the following sequence of numbers will be generated for n = 22:

22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
It is conjectured (but not yet proven) that this algorithm will terminate at n = 1 for every integer n. Still, the conjecture holds for all integers up to at least 1, 000, 000.
For an input n, the cycle-length of n is the number of numbers generated up to and including the 1. In the example above, the cycle length of 22 is 16. Given any two numbers i and j, you are to determine the maximum cycle length over all numbers between i and j, including both endpoints.

Input

The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers i and j, one pair of integers per line. All integers will be less than 1,000,000 and greater than 0.

Output

For each pair of input integers i and j, output i, j in the same order in which they appeared in the input and then the maximum cycle length for integers between and including i and j. These three numbers should be separated by one space, with all three numbers on one line and with one line of output for each line of input.

Sample Input

1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000

Sample Output

1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174

The acceptable solution is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int cylen(int n){

    int count = 1;
    while (n !=1 ){
        if (n%2 == 0)
            n = n/2;
        else
            n = 3*n +1;
    ++count;
    }
return count;
}
int maxcylen(int s, int e){
int tmp,i,maxcy, sz;

    if(s>e){
        tmp =s;
        s = e;
        e = tmp;
    }

    maxcy = 0;
    for(i=s;i<=e;i++){
        sz = cylen(i);
        if (sz> maxcy)
            maxcy  =sz;
    }
return maxcy;
}
int main(){
int s,e;
while(scanf("%d %d", &s, &e) != EOF){

    printf("%d %d %d\n",s,e,maxcylen(s,e));
}
return 0;
}
```

The unacceptable one is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int cylen(int n){

int count = 1;
while (n !=1 ){
    if (n%2 == 0)
        n = n/2;
    else
        n = 3*n +1;
    ++count;
    }
return count;
}
int main(){
int s,e, tmp,i,maxcy, sz;
while(scanf("%d %d", &s, &e) != EOF){
    if(s>e){
        tmp =s;
        s = e;
        e = tmp;
    }

    maxcy = 0;
    for(i=s;i<=e;i++){
        sz = cylen(i);
        if (sz> maxcy)
            maxcy  =sz;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n",s,e,maxcy);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix indentation... Problem is tabs, best not to use them in SO questions.

Comment: Note: for future code, consider `while(scanf("%d %d", &s, &e) == 2)`.  Should you succeed in scanning only 1, you likely want to not continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in first solution you have two variables `s` and `e` which are defined in main function and two separate variables `s` and `e` which are defined only in `maxcylen` function

these variables are totally different ones

in first solution you're modifying `s` and `e`, but only inside function, so during output of result *old* ones from `main` are displayed, and this is right solution

to fix second solution, you need to do this:

```
int s,e, tmp,i,maxcy, sz, originalS, originalE; // note 2 additional variables
while(scanf("%d %d", &s, &e) != EOF){
    originalS = s; // storing of values from file
    originalE = e;
    if(s>e){
        tmp =s;
        s = e;
        e = tmp;
    }

    maxcy = 0;
    for(i=s;i<=e;i++){
        sz = cylen(i);
        if (sz> maxcy)
            maxcy  =sz;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n",originalS,originalE,maxcy); // output of variables from file, instead of modified ones
}
```